# Virus: Going on earth. Any solution?

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

i have a some kind of virus in system. Whenever I google something and click on any of the result links, it redirects my browser to some site goingonearth. I have tried some of the solutions available on net, but none seem to be working. I dont know how harmfull this virus is. Can it hack my mail ids? can it delete my important data from system? How do i fix this thing?

OS: Windows 7

Antivirus: heck-of-a-fee (McAfee)

Comment: I'd try SpyBot - [link](http://www.safer-networking.org)  and SuperAntiSpyware - [link](http://www.superantispyware.com). These have got me out of trouble plenty of times.

Comment: @bubble: Being rude isn't going to help.

Comment: Please try to read the first comment on the mentioned question. This is exactly the case here. Please vote to open this question as none of the solution are working

Comment: Please don't edit out the **automatically** added duplicate link. If the question is reopened it will be removed.

Comment: If we believe the anti-virus companies, there are 100s of 1000s of different viruses. We don't want a topic for every single one of them, that'd be insanity. Besides, we expect our users to think for themselves and do a little research. If you did, include that in your question.

Comment: I mentioned it in the question "I have tried some of the solutions available on net, but none seem to be working.", I thought it will be okay. Besides if you google this thing you will find many posts and many user are not able to get rid of it using those solutions. some sites say it is specifically designed to defeat mcAfee. Also I have tried all the solutions mentioned here and they are not working. Doesn't this makes it a threat worth discussing?

Comment: @ChrisF thanks for that actually I intended to rollback some changes in my question heading only.

Comment: and even after 2 weeks the problem remains as it was. tried all the things given here. installed numerous malewared detectors and what not. still the virus/malware remains. Please allow this question or specify why this question should remain closed even now.

Comment: this post has recieved 430 views. I guess many people want the solution. Consider opening this question.

Answer (score 1):

Methods for cleaning up a virus infection vary, the following is my preference. This may not be the most thorough way to remove a virus infection, but whenever I've had to deal with one I do the following:

1. Download [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (the free version)
2. Update the virus definitions
3. Restart the computer in safe mode (no networking)
4. Perform the most thorough scan and clean that is offered.

There are cases where this won't be enough to fix the problem, but every virus I've cleaned up for a family member has met its doom at the hands of Malwarebytes.

Comment: tried and its not working

Answer (score 0):

The 2 anti-virus solutions I recommend are Microsoft Security Essentials and Malwarebytes, both free.

Also, there are a number of security sites which will do a free scan of your computer and try to fix the problem. Here's a link to 10 of them. Good luck.

Comment: Is it some general solution or you are specific to this virus?

Comment: General solution.

Comment: No link in your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

goingonearth dot com is a classic kind of browser hijacker. if existing in the classic form, it should not be hijacking your mailid/stealing files. of course you can't be that sure if it's something else combined with goingonearth.

follow the following instructions:

```
boot into safe mode.
stop the task sstray.exe (if running)
delete all mazuki.dll that you can find on your harddisk
```

Comment: just tried this one. no process like sstray.exe was active also a search for mazuki.dll returned zero results

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Malwarebytes Antimalware and CCleaner.

Reboot your computer and go into safemode.

Run Malwarebytes Antimalware and let it clean everything it finds. Reboot into normal mode and run Malwarebytes again. Then use CCleaner to clean the temporary files on your computer.

Simple redirect viruses like this usually don't do anything too terrible. However, various variants could have more nefarious payloads.

As a precaution, you should change passwords to all your various website accounts, especially banking sites, and keep a close eye on your bank accounts for a few weeks to make sure someone didn't get more than we hope they did.

Comment: tried and its not working

Comment: Then that means whatever process is running the malware is probably still running in safemode. Unless, that is, you failed to update MBAM prior to running it. But I'll assume you did. If this is the case, you need to remove your HDD and place it in a different computer as a slave or secondary drive, and scan it using the same tools as well as the antivirus software installed on that other computer.

Comment: i updated it prior to running

Comment: I have a laptop and removing a HDD is not going to be easy

Comment: That's true. An easier option may then be to use a Live CD of Ubuntu or some bootable antivirus tool. It may be helpful when doing it this way, to get a list of the files you want to delete, as many LiveCDs or bootable AV tools don't have as up-to-date virus definition files. Knowing what files you want to delete allows you to quickly remove those, then when back in windows, even if there are still start up and reg entries calling those files, they won't be there to run and the final cleanup is easier.